# in postgresql copy specific colums to destination table will have always 7 days data older data should be deleted autometically

Tags: postgresql

I have joined a project as a DBA. But I do not have knowledge in scripting. I have a task to copy specific columns from source to destination table and the destination table should have always 7 days data and older than 7 days data should be deleted automatically. Please help me on this .

any comment will be greatly appriciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds more like a `VIEW` to me. Why do you have to copy the data? And do you intend to have this run on a scheduled basis?

Comment: Hi Frank, I have crated a function for copying data from one table to another in the same schema. I is working but when I am running the function it tranfaring 3 months data but I need only 7 days data in my destination table everyday, the older data more than 7 days must be deleted automatically.

Comment: Hi Bergi, thank you for your reply. Please suggest me how to write the code to transfer 7 days data of n number of columns everyday older than 7 days data must be deleted by running a job. please suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Utpal Please [edit] your question to include the code that you've written which doesn't work